# Will the Chainlink VRF event make the requested randomness public?

Tags: chainlink

The code in VRFCoordinatorV2.sol indicates that a `RandomWordsFulfilled` event will be emitted, containing the `outputSeed` parameter (also known as `randomness`). Will this event expose the requested random number(s) to other users or miners/validators? Is it possible for others to retrieve the numbers from the event (or other ways)?

join chainlinks discord & telegram to find answer

Answer (score 0):

The event is public/readable however the randomness and the value returned to the VRF caller are not actually the same.

The user gets the keccak256 hash of `abi.encode(randomness, i)` where i is the zero-indexed # of random words requested.

See this line
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFCoordinatorV2.sol#L535

In theory miners/validators can if they make the effort see the output since they execute the transaction and see all log outputs.

Hence why best practice is that generally, the vrf output being delivered to a consumer contract should decide an output (e.g a particular NFT trait, a roll of the dice, a card shuffle, etc. etc.) and be discarded thereafter....

It should not be saved to be used beyond that because it'll no longer be truly random (i.e if you store it in the contract and maybe have the user use it some later point in time, they can simulate the transaction and see that they lose a lot of money, and choose not to interact with the contract)

hope that helps.